# How to randomly generate points in a line?

Tags: plotting, random

### For example,how to randomly generate 100 points in line L:y=x,and x~N(0,1).

Edit:I mean,for point p(x,y),x=t,y=t,t is random variable，and t~N(0,1).Randomly generate 100 points like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
{#, #} & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]
% // Point // Graphics
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

line = Line[{{-3, -3}, {3, 3}}];

SeedRandom[1234];
```

For uniformly distributed points on the line

```
ptsU = RandomPoint[line, 1000];
```

For normally distributed points on the line

```
ptsN = RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{-3, 3},
     NormalDistribution[]], 1000];

Histogram[{ptsN, ptsU[[All, 1]]}, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
Graphics[
 Table[Point[{tmp = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 
    tmp}], {100}]]
```